# passing json to kendoui grid

Tags: json, kendo-ui

I would really appreciate guidance. 
My script will make a call to my server, grab some data and bring it back as JSON.  Then I call ServiceSucceeded(msg); I pass in the JSON results in msg.  Now in ServiceSucceeded I want to display my results on kendoui grid. That is the part that I can't get to work. It gives no browser errors.
This code might be awful, so please school me on this , thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/telerik/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/telerik/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

        <script src="../../assets/telerik/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../assets/telerik/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="grid">

    </div>
    <div>
        <script>
            var Type;
            var Url;
            var Data;
            var ContentType;
            var DataType;
            var ProcessData;
            var Username;
            var Password;
            var qryVar;
            var locationName;


            function GetAllReportDB() {
                var dataId = "1";
                Type = "GET";
                qryVar = "userName=Simon"
                Url = "http://localhost/UserReportMap.svc/GetAllReportDB?" + qryVar;
                Data = '{"Contains": "Kir","DBName":"Bony","Operator":"BON0D"}';
                ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                DataType = "json"; ProcessData = true;
                Username = "test";
                Password = "test";

                CallService();

            }

            function CallService() {


                $.support.cors = true;
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url: Url, // Location of the service
                    data: Data, //Data sent to server
                    contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
                    dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
                    processdata: ProcessData, //True or False


                    beforeSend: function (xhr2) {
                        xhr2.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa(Username + ':' + Password));
                    },


                    success: function (msg) {


                        ServiceSucceeded(msg);
                        alert("Succeeded");
                    },
                    error: function (errMsg) {
                        alert("Fail!");
                    }
                });
            }


            function ServiceSucceeded(msg) {
                var myResults = { "d": [{msg}] };
                alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
                $(function () {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataType: "json",
                        schem: {
                            data: "d"

                        }
                        //columns: [{ title: "First Name" },
                          //       { title: "Last Name" }]
                    });
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(
       function () {
           GetAllReportDB();

       }
   );
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have one typo at schem. It should be *schema* and not *schem*.

Anyway, I recommend check [API docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid), there is written what you need.

And to your question:

You are missing dataSource in your grid so it doesn't know from what data grid should be rendered.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
    type: "json",
    data: jsonData,
    pageSize: 20
    }, 
    ...
});
```

So line *var myResults = { "d": [{msg}] };* can be removed and msg data can be assigned into dataSource. Then you will be able to set columns - [here demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/enEKi)

And also consider, if you need load your json data in function and result assign into variable. Grid is able to load data from server without that - server just has to return json data, like in [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/mvvm)